# Which IDF to choose for ESP32 developent team

Tags: esp32

I and my friends are getting started with ESP-IDF. We want to get familiar with Embedded C development and ESp32 seemed to be a very good candidate for our later needs. The problem is there are several versions of ESP-IDF and we are especially worried about their being separate Legacy GNU version for 32bit and Newer recommended [based on CMake] one for 64 bit. Not all of my friends have 64bit Windows and it seems the installation process is also a little different for legacy. Also, the getting started page for Legacy version says it will eventually be removed.

Also aside from this, the master branch of IDF is the latest 64bit one, and stable versions include both 64bit and legacy GNU for 32-bit. So, if only some members of our group having 32-bit system install legacy gnu and others with 64bit systems install the master branch version, will every one of us be on the same page, after the installation?

Is there any difference in the development process of an ESP32 program using Legacy GNU(on a 32-bit system) and CMAKE (on a 64-bit system)?